# Error while installing lmql[hf] using pip: "No matching distribution found for lmql[hf]

Tags: python, pip, bert-language-model, language-model, large-language-model

I am trying to install lmql[hf] using the pip package manager in order to set up a local LMQL playground. Following the [documentation](https://docs.lmql.ai/en/stable/language/hf.html), I ran the command `pip install lmql[hf]`.

However, I encountered the following error:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.0.2 Requires-Python >=3.9; 0.0.2.1 Requires-Python >=3.9; 0.0.3.0 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.3.1 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.4 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.4.1 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.4.2 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.5 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.5.1 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.6 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.6.1 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.6.2 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.6.3 Requires-Python >=3.10; 0.0.6.4 Requires-Python >=3.10
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lmql[hf] (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lmql[hf]
```

I have ensured that my pip package manager is up to date by running `pip install --upgrade pip`, but the error persists.

Python 3.11

pip 23.1.2

Any guidance or assistance in resolving this installation issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I expect to run lmql with a local language model e.g. `bert-base-uncased` loacally

Comment: Show us the output of `pip --version`

Comment: Did you mistake pip of python2 as pip of python3?

Comment: I have the same result for `pip3 install lmql\[hf\]`

Comment: I wanted to see the **full** output of `pip --version`, because it also includes the version of Python it is linked to.

Comment: pip 23.1.2 from /Users/sparql/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: Well, that's the problem then.  You're using Python 3.11 to run the code, but pip installed the module for python 3.8.

Comment: You need to decide what version of python you want to use, and then configure your environment so that all the supporting tools agree on the version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found using quotations or using `pip install "lmql[hf]"` instead to work.

I think without the quotes the command is parsed incorrectly but I don't know the specifics.